# PCM Palladio Factory Builder for Model-2-Model transformation in Xtend

Tags: xtext, xtend

I have created a DSL in Xtext and I am now working on creating a code generator in Xtend. I implement this code generator using the DslGenerator Xtend file which is automatically created when 'compiling' the DSL defined in Xtext. So far so good.

I screwed around a bit with the Xtend language and all it's nice features (including template expressions) to see what the code generator is capable of. I did some simple Model-to-Text transformations, and I am not trying to implement Model-to-Model transformations. I want to create a code generator that allows to transform my DSL-based models to PCM Palladio Models. The PCM Palladio model is a framework used for modelling and simulating software. Part of the framework are some packages which allow programmers to instantiate PCM models through EMF-generated model factories (see their [site](https://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/wiki/PCM_Development/Model_Builder_Factories)). Mind that the code example on their site is in Java. I have copied and adapted this code in my Xtend code generator as can be seen below.

```
def builder () {
    var res = new XMLResourceImpl(URI.createFileURI("TestFile.txt"))
    var repository = RepositoryFactory.eINSTANCE.createRepository();
    repository.setEntityName("Repository containing other elements");
    // add root (repository) to resource:
    res.getContents().add(repository);

    var bc = RepositoryFactory.eINSTANCE.createBasicComponent();
    bc.setEntityName("My Basic Component");
    repository.getComponents__Repository().add(bc);  //add first class entity

    var myInterface = RepositoryFactory.eINSTANCE.createOperationInterface();
    myInterface.setEntityName("My Interface");
    repository.getInterfaces__Repository().add(myInterface); //add first class entity

    var opProvRole = RepositoryFactory.eINSTANCE.createOperationProvidedRole();
    opProvRole.setEntityName("Provided Role of Basic Component");

    // set the interface for the role:
    opProvRole.setProvidedInterface__OperationProvidedRole(myInterface);

    // set/add the role for basic component:
    bc.getProvidedRoles_InterfaceProvidingEntity().add(opProvRole);
    return repository
    }
```

The thing is that the file I expect to appear ("TestFile.txt") does not appear. I have tried numerous ways to get it to work, but I am not sure on how to implement this. Model-to-Text transformations are not a problem anymore, but Model-to-Model transformations (using builder factories) are not really working yet. The output model finally has to be something like the code below; an XML-like file which can be read by Palladio PCM framework (the code below is just an example of a file I created manually with the Palladio PCM framework).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<repository:Repository xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:repository="http://palladiosimulator.org/PalladioComponentModel/Repository/5.2" xmlns:seff="http://palladiosimulator.org/PalladioComponentModel/SEFF/5.2" xmlns:stoex="http://sdq.ipd.uka.de/StochasticExpressions/2.2" id="_Gzo5EMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="PcmStandardRepository" repositoryDescription="This projects holds a repository with a set of standard reusable software components and interfaces. These components and interfaces can be used across multiple projects to ease starting modeling.">
  <components__Repository xsi:type="repository:BasicComponent" id="_li9tIMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="Cache">
    <providedRoles_InterfaceProvidingEntity xsi:type="repository:OperationProvidedRole" id="_n1kB4MuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="Provided_IRequest_Cache" providedInterface__OperationProvidedRole="_H-m3YMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
    <requiredRoles_InterfaceRequiringEntity xsi:type="repository:OperationRequiredRole" id="_oWqj0MuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="Required_IRequest_Cache" requiredInterface__OperationRequiredRole="_H-m3YMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
    <serviceEffectSpecifications__BasicComponent xsi:type="seff:ResourceDemandingSEFF" id="_n1qIgMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" describedService__SEFF="_JcqJwMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw">
      <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StartAction" id="_n1qIgcuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="start" successor_AbstractAction="_IyWWkMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
      <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StopAction" id="_n1qIgsuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="stop" predecessor_AbstractAction="__PBwwMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
      <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:InternalAction" id="_IyWWkMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="CacheLookup" predecessor_AbstractAction="_n1qIgcuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" successor_AbstractAction="_Sz5UAMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw">
        <resourceDemand_Action>
          <specification_ParametericResourceDemand specification="1"/>
          <requiredResource_ParametricResourceDemand href="pathmap://PCM_MODELS/Palladio.resourcetype#_oro4gG3fEdy4YaaT-RYrLQ"/>
        </resourceDemand_Action>
      </steps_Behaviour>
      <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:BranchAction" id="_Sz5UAMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="CacheHitMiss" predecessor_AbstractAction="_IyWWkMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" successor_AbstractAction="__PBwwMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw">
        <branches_Branch xsi:type="seff:ProbabilisticBranchTransition" id="_WyeCYMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="CacheHit" branchProbability="0.8">
          <branchBehaviour_BranchTransition id="_WyeCYcuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw">
            <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StartAction" id="_WykJAMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" successor_AbstractAction="_WykJAcuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
            <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StopAction" id="_WykJAcuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" predecessor_AbstractAction="_WykJAMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
          </branchBehaviour_BranchTransition>
        </branches_Branch>
        <branches_Branch xsi:type="seff:ProbabilisticBranchTransition" id="_ZbkyoMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="CacheMiss" branchProbability="0.2">
          <branchBehaviour_BranchTransition id="_ZbkyocuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw">
            <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StartAction" id="_ZbkyosuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" successor_AbstractAction="_ovu5MMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
            <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StopAction" id="_Zbkyo8uyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" predecessor_AbstractAction="_ovu5MMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
            <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:ExternalCallAction" id="_ovu5MMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" predecessor_AbstractAction="_ZbkyosuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" successor_AbstractAction="_Zbkyo8uyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" calledService_ExternalService="_JcqJwMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" role_ExternalService="_oWqj0MuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw">
              <inputVariableUsages__CallAction>
                <variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage type="VALUE">
                  <specification_VariableCharacterisation specification="requestType.VALUE"/>
                </variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage>
                <namedReference__VariableUsage xsi:type="stoex:VariableReference" referenceName="requestType"/>
              </inputVariableUsages__CallAction>
              <returnVariableUsage__CallReturnAction>
                <variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage type="VALUE">
                  <specification_VariableCharacterisation specification="RETURN.VALUE"/>
                </variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage>
                <namedReference__VariableUsage xsi:type="stoex:VariableReference" referenceName="externalCallResponse"/>
              </returnVariableUsage__CallReturnAction>
            </steps_Behaviour>
          </branchBehaviour_BranchTransition>
        </branches_Branch>
      </steps_Behaviour>
      <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:SetVariableAction" id="__PBwwMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="setReturnValue" predecessor_AbstractAction="_Sz5UAMuyEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" successor_AbstractAction="_n1qIgsuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw">
        <localVariableUsages_SetVariableAction>
          <variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage type="VALUE">
            <specification_VariableCharacterisation specification="externalCallResponse.VALUE"/>
          </variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage>
          <namedReference__VariableUsage xsi:type="stoex:VariableReference" referenceName="RETURN"/>
        </localVariableUsages_SetVariableAction>
      </steps_Behaviour>
    </serviceEffectSpecifications__BasicComponent>
  </components__Repository>
  <components__Repository xsi:type="repository:BasicComponent" id="_KpCn4MuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="StandardForwardingComponent">
    <providedRoles_InterfaceProvidingEntity xsi:type="repository:OperationProvidedRole" id="_Ljy_8MuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="Provided_IRequest_Forwarder" providedInterface__OperationProvidedRole="_H-m3YMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
    <requiredRoles_InterfaceRequiringEntity xsi:type="repository:OperationRequiredRole" id="_MD1x8MuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="Required_IRequest_Forwarder" requiredInterface__OperationRequiredRole="_H-m3YMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
    <serviceEffectSpecifications__BasicComponent xsi:type="seff:ResourceDemandingSEFF" id="_Ljy_8cuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" describedService__SEFF="_JcqJwMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw">
      <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StartAction" id="_Ljy_8suxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="start" successor_AbstractAction="_d2mo8MuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
      <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StopAction" id="_Ljy_88uxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="stop" predecessor_AbstractAction="_lJaIMMuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
      <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:ExternalCallAction" id="_Mps4EMuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" predecessor_AbstractAction="_d2mo8MuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" successor_AbstractAction="_lJaIMMuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" calledService_ExternalService="_JcqJwMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" role_ExternalService="_MD1x8MuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw">
        <inputVariableUsages__CallAction>
          <variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage type="VALUE">
            <specification_VariableCharacterisation specification="requestType.VALUE"/>
          </variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage>
          <namedReference__VariableUsage xsi:type="stoex:VariableReference" referenceName="requestType"/>
        </inputVariableUsages__CallAction>
        <returnVariableUsage__CallReturnAction>
          <variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage type="VALUE">
            <specification_VariableCharacterisation specification="RETURN.VALUE"/>
          </variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage>
          <namedReference__VariableUsage xsi:type="stoex:VariableReference" referenceName="externalCallResponse"/>
        </returnVariableUsage__CallReturnAction>
      </steps_Behaviour>
      <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:InternalAction" id="_d2mo8MuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="ComponentRessourceUsage" predecessor_AbstractAction="_Ljy_8suxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" successor_AbstractAction="_Mps4EMuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw">
        <resourceDemand_Action>
          <specification_ParametericResourceDemand specification="0"/>
          <requiredResource_ParametricResourceDemand href="pathmap://PCM_MODELS/Palladio.resourcetype#_oro4gG3fEdy4YaaT-RYrLQ"/>
        </resourceDemand_Action>
        <resourceDemand_Action>
          <specification_ParametericResourceDemand specification="0"/>
          <requiredResource_ParametricResourceDemand href="pathmap://PCM_MODELS/Palladio.resourcetype#_BIjHoQ3KEdyouMqirZIhzQ"/>
        </resourceDemand_Action>
      </steps_Behaviour>
      <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:SetVariableAction" id="_lJaIMMuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="setReturnValue" predecessor_AbstractAction="_Mps4EMuxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" successor_AbstractAction="_Ljy_88uxEeOrXJYSTPO-kw">
        <localVariableUsages_SetVariableAction>
          <variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage type="VALUE">
            <specification_VariableCharacterisation specification="externalCallResponse.VALUE"/>
          </variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage>
          <namedReference__VariableUsage xsi:type="stoex:VariableReference" referenceName="RETURN"/>
        </localVariableUsages_SetVariableAction>
      </steps_Behaviour>
      <resourceDemandingInternalBehaviours id="_IXB-DoxVEemBWcwyLC2p7g"/>
    </serviceEffectSpecifications__BasicComponent>
  </components__Repository>
  <components__Repository xsi:type="repository:BasicComponent" id="_SQwdkMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" entityName="LoadBalancer2x">
    <providedRoles_InterfaceProvidingEntity xsi:type="repository:OperationProvidedRole" id="_V0b_sMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" entityName="Provided_IRequest_LoadBalancer2x" providedInterface__OperationProvidedRole="_H-m3YMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
    <requiredRoles_InterfaceRequiringEntity xsi:type="repository:OperationRequiredRole" id="_USYXEMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" entityName="Required_IRequest_LoadBalancer2x_Port01" requiredInterface__OperationRequiredRole="_H-m3YMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
    <requiredRoles_InterfaceRequiringEntity xsi:type="repository:OperationRequiredRole" id="_Ux2hUMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" entityName="Required_IRequest_LoadBalancer2x_Port02" requiredInterface__OperationRequiredRole="_H-m3YMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw"/>
    <serviceEffectSpecifications__BasicComponent xsi:type="seff:ResourceDemandingSEFF" id="_V0iGUMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" describedService__SEFF="_JcqJwMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw">
      <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StartAction" id="_V0iGUcxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" entityName="start" successor_AbstractAction="_YLD40MxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg"/>
      <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StopAction" id="_V0iGUsxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" entityName="stop" predecessor_AbstractAction="_YLD40MxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg"/>
      <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:BranchAction" id="_YLD40MxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" entityName="RandomlyChoseRequiredPorts" predecessor_AbstractAction="_V0iGUcxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" successor_AbstractAction="_V0iGUsxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg">
        <branches_Branch xsi:type="seff:ProbabilisticBranchTransition" id="_de5xAMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" entityName="CallPort01" branchProbability="0.5">
          <branchBehaviour_BranchTransition id="_de5xAcxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg">
            <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StartAction" id="_de_3oMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" successor_AbstractAction="_ei6LsMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg"/>
            <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StopAction" id="_de_3ocxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" predecessor_AbstractAction="_ei6LsMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg"/>
            <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:ExternalCallAction" id="_ei6LsMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" predecessor_AbstractAction="_de_3oMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" successor_AbstractAction="_de_3ocxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" calledService_ExternalService="_JcqJwMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" role_ExternalService="_USYXEMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg">
              <inputVariableUsages__CallAction>
                <variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage type="VALUE">
                  <specification_VariableCharacterisation specification="requestType.VALUE"/>
                </variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage>
                <namedReference__VariableUsage xsi:type="stoex:VariableReference" referenceName="requestType"/>
              </inputVariableUsages__CallAction>
            </steps_Behaviour>
          </branchBehaviour_BranchTransition>
        </branches_Branch>
        <branches_Branch xsi:type="seff:ProbabilisticBranchTransition" id="_lVrgAMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" entityName="CallPort02" branchProbability="0.5">
          <branchBehaviour_BranchTransition id="_lVrgAcxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg">
            <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StartAction" id="_lVrgAsxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" successor_AbstractAction="_miRO8MxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg"/>
            <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:StopAction" id="_lVrgA8xpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" predecessor_AbstractAction="_miRO8MxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg"/>
            <steps_Behaviour xsi:type="seff:ExternalCallAction" id="_miRO8MxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" predecessor_AbstractAction="_lVrgAsxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" successor_AbstractAction="_lVrgA8xpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg" calledService_ExternalService="_JcqJwMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" role_ExternalService="_Ux2hUMxpEeOx-JIRUcYdjg">
              <inputVariableUsages__CallAction>
                <variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage type="VALUE">
                  <specification_VariableCharacterisation specification="requestType.VALUE"/>
                </variableCharacterisation_VariableUsage>
                <namedReference__VariableUsage xsi:type="stoex:VariableReference" referenceName="requestType"/>
              </inputVariableUsages__CallAction>
            </steps_Behaviour>
          </branchBehaviour_BranchTransition>
        </branches_Branch>
      </steps_Behaviour>
    </serviceEffectSpecifications__BasicComponent>
  </components__Repository>
  <interfaces__Repository xsi:type="repository:OperationInterface" id="_H-m3YMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="IRequest">
    <signatures__OperationInterface id="_JcqJwMuwEeOrXJYSTPO-kw" entityName="processRequest">
      <parameters__OperationSignature parameterName="requestType">
        <dataType__Parameter xsi:type="repository:PrimitiveDataType" href="pathmap://PCM_MODELS/PrimitiveTypes.repository#//@dataTypes__Repository.1"/>
      </parameters__OperationSignature>
      <returnType__OperationSignature xsi:type="repository:PrimitiveDataType" href="pathmap://PCM_MODELS/PrimitiveTypes.repository#//@dataTypes__Repository.0"/>
    </signatures__OperationInterface>
  </interfaces__Repository>
</repository:Repository>
```

EDIT to Lorenzo's first answer:

Hi Lorenzo thanks for answering. I have solved a few things and have managed to create a modelBuilder function now which can create PCM Palladio repository models now. The code of the function, and the model that is generated through this function are shown below. The good thing is that the created model is a 'valid' repository model (it complies with the syntax as illustrated by the example model that I initially posted). However, PCM Palladio requires another .repository_diagram model to edit the model in the graphical modelling environment. If I now click on the generated model  to open it with the PCM Repository Model Diagram editor, I get the error message: 'Cannot open input element, Resource contains no diagram'. Do you know (or anyone else) how I can create a 'full' PCM repository model together with all of its required models, so that the generated models can be opened and edited with the Graphical PCM model editors?

Code of modelBuilder function:

```
def modelBuilder () {

        // This part of the code is still a bit unclear for me.
    var injector = new FinalDslStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration()
    var resourceSet = injector.getInstance(ResourceSet)
    EcoreUtil.resolveAll(resourceSet)

        //Create repository to store Model Elemenents (BasicComponents, Operation Interfaces etc.)
    var repositoryResult = new XMLResourceImpl()
    var repository = RepositoryFactory.eINSTANCE.createRepository
    repository.setEntityName("Repository containing other elements")

        // add root (repository) to resource:
    repositoryResult.getContents().add(repository)

    var bc = RepositoryFactory.eINSTANCE.createBasicComponent()
    bc.setEntityName("My Basic Component")
        //add first class entity
    repository.getComponents__Repository().add(bc)  

    var myInterface = RepositoryFactory.eINSTANCE.createOperationInterface()
    myInterface.setEntityName("My Interface")
        //add first class entity
    repository.getInterfaces__Repository().add(myInterface); 

    var opProvRole = RepositoryFactory.eINSTANCE.createOperationProvidedRole()
    opProvRole.setEntityName("Provided Role of Basic Component")

        // set the interface for the role:
    opProvRole.setProvidedInterface__OperationProvidedRole(myInterface)

        // set/add the role for basic component:
    bc.getProvidedRoles_InterfaceProvidingEntity().add(opProvRole)

        // Save the repositoryResult in
    var location2 = URI.createURI("platform:/resource/finaldsl/TestRepository.repository")
    var xmiResource2 = resourceSet.createResource(location2)
        xmiResource2.getContents().add(repositoryResult.getContents().get(0))
        xmiResource2.save(null)

}
```

PCM Palladio repository model that is generated through the modelBuilder function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<repository:Repository xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:repository="http://palladiosimulator.org/PalladioComponentModel/Repository/5.2" id="_urk-0OYtEem_g6oW0m4J9A" entityName="Repository containing other elements">
  <components__Repository xsi:type="repository:BasicComponent" id="_urk-0eYtEem_g6oW0m4J9A" entityName="My Basic Component">
    <providedRoles_InterfaceProvidingEntity xsi:type="repository:OperationProvidedRole" id="_urk-0-YtEem_g6oW0m4J9A" entityName="Provided Role of Basic Component" providedInterface__OperationProvidedRole="_urk-0uYtEem_g6oW0m4J9A"/>
  </components__Repository>
  <interfaces__Repository xsi:type="repository:OperationInterface" id="_urk-0uYtEem_g6oW0m4J9A" entityName="My Interface"/>
</repository:Repository>
```

Edit to Lorzenzo's second answer:

```
/*
 * generated by Xtext 2.17.1
 */
package org.xtext.example.mydsl.generator

import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreUtil
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.AbstractGenerator
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IFileSystemAccess2
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IGeneratorContext
import org.palladiosimulator.pcm.repository.RepositoryFactory
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.FinalDslStandaloneSetup

/**
 * Generates code from your model files on save.
 * 
 * See https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/303_runtime_concepts.html#code-generation
 */
class FinalDslGenerator extends AbstractGenerator {


override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context ) {

    // Method call to build and store PCM Palladio repository. Rigt click on the repository file
    // to create a .repository_diagram file to 'graphically' view and edit the repostiry accordingly.
    RepositoryBuilder()

    // Method call to build and store your modelled DSL instance accordingly. Mind that this has nothing
    // to do with the creation of the PCM Palladio repository above, but it might come in handy if you want
    // to export your DSL instances (for use outside of the xText IDE environment).
    ModelXMLBuilder(resource)

    }

def RepositoryBuilder () {

    var repository = RepositoryFactory.eINSTANCE.createRepository
    repository.setEntityName("Repository containing other elements")

    // add root (repository) to resource:
    var bc = RepositoryFactory.eINSTANCE.createBasicComponent()
    bc.setEntityName("My Basic Component")
    repository.getComponents__Repository().add(bc)  //add first class entity

    var myInterface = RepositoryFactory.eINSTANCE.createOperationInterface()
    myInterface.setEntityName("My Interface")
    repository.getInterfaces__Repository().add(myInterface); //add first class entity

    var opProvRole = RepositoryFactory.eINSTANCE.createOperationProvidedRole()
    opProvRole.setEntityName("Provided Role of Basic Component")

    // set the interface for the role:
    opProvRole.setProvidedInterface__OperationProvidedRole(myInterface)

    // set/add the role for basic component:
    bc.getProvidedRoles_InterfaceProvidingEntity().add(opProvRole)

    var storeURI = URI.createURI("platform:/resource/finaldsl/src-gen/TestRepository.repository")
    var result = new ResourceSetImpl().createResource(storeURI)
        result.getContents().add(repository)
        result.save(null)
    }


def ModelXMLBuilder (Resource dslInstance) {
    var injector = new FinalDslStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration()
    var resourceSet = injector.getInstance(ResourceSet)

    dslInstance.load(null)
    EcoreUtil.resolveAll(resourceSet)

    var location = URI.createURI("platform:/resource/finaldsl/src-gen/DSL-XMI-Model.xmi")       
    var xmiResource = resourceSet.createResource(location)
        xmiResource.getContents().add(dslInstance.getContents().get(0))
        xmiResource.save(null)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saving the created resource somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for answering, see my answer in the EDIT part of my initial post.

Comment: You could construct the .repository_diagram model in the same way as you are currently creating the .repository ones. The diagram model probably contains references to the .repository model, hence constructing these alongside might be necessary. Unfortunately, I can not think of any optimal way to programmatically dispose the graphical representations in the diagram (you will need to that manually, I suppose). Are you planning to edit the generated models with non-xtext editors?

Comment: Hi Lorenzo. Thanks again for answering. I managed to create the diagram file manually. The trick was indeed to create the repository file with the corresponding .repository extension (up until now I was screwing around and added a .txt extension to every file), but with the .repository extension added I was indeed presented with the option to create a diagram file when right-clicking on the created repository file. It would be nice-to-have to programmatically create the diagram file, but for now it's OK. I don't plan on using it in non-xText editors, so it's fine this way.

Comment: By the way see the second edit in my initial post. I posted clean and working source code together with the required import packages. This code can be put in the Generator.Xtend file in the org.xtext.example.mydsl.generator package. I added two methods, one for building the PCM Palladio repository file and one for building an XML file containing your modelled DSL instance (see comments in source code for elaboration). Mind that you have to refer to these packages in your plugin.xml file (in the dependencies tab of the plugin.xml file) and in the MANIFEST.MF, otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: Also mind that you have to adapt the source code to the name of your DSL. For example, I called my dsl 'FinalDsl'. Of course you have to adapt this part to the name of your own DSL; e.g. 'import org.xtext.example.mydsl.FinalDslStandaloneSetup' should become 'import org.xtext.example.mydsl.*YourDslName*StandaloneSetup'